# How to make parallel cURL requests in php?

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, request, webserver

I have a php code on my server and in this code I would like to execute multiple `cURL` requests in parallel.

Each cURL request is used to analyze the bees of a website and therefore I do not want to execute the requests in "sequence" but in **parallel** (so the execution of the script will be shorter).
I tried to use **multi-threaded** but i get this error:

**Class 'Thread' not found**

```
   class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
        public function request() {
            first_request();
        }
    }       
    
    // Crea un array
    $stack = array();

    // crea i thread
    foreach ( range("A", "D") as $i ) {
        $stack[] = new AsyncOperation($i);
    }

    // avvia i thread
    foreach ( $stack as $h ) {
        $h->start();
    }
```

I don't know if the error depends on the code or maybe because I can't use multi-threading ...
How can i solve this or to do many requests in parallel ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: curl multi will do that without threads https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone really works ? it takes 5 seconds to execute my request.

If I make 10 requests using curl_multi_exec will my code still only take 5 seconds?

Comment: yes it will fire off all the requests at once (examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A661872+curl_multi_exec)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone great i try it ! i have only one doubt... so what's the difference with muti-thread ?

Comment: [Thread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread) your need to add pthreads

Comment: When using PHP8.1+ you can use Fibers.